# FFmpeg/x264 “subq” or “subme” Settings

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264, libx264, mencoder

I am using FFmpeg 4, FFmpeg x264 has an option called “subq” or “subme”, the document mentioned the default is ‘6’, but I tried to skip this option, then if I use “MediaInfo” to check the output video, the default should be ‘0’ instead of ‘6’. The document doesn’t’ mention about ’0’, anybody knows?

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 8000k -maxrate 8000k -bufsize 8000k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -g 90 -async 2

Comment: @Gyan pls check above

Comment: You haven't set subq or subme, so its default value will be used.